# Multiple form include symfony (same page)

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with multiple form symfony (include).

I have a multiple article in the same page, the user can add comment for each article. I would like to show the form add comment.

My problem is this : when I submit my comment adding form, Symfony does not save the information in the database (without error message).

I tried to add a class for to change the name of my form, but it's the same.

My form action in the controller (call by the twig view for each article)

```
public function formAction($post_id, Request $request) {
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $post = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->find($post_id);

    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment -> setPost($post);
    $comment -> setAuthor($user);

    $form_comment = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);

    $form_comment->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form_comment->isSubmitted()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($comment);
        $em->flush();

        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('msg_success', 'Votre contribution a bien été ajoutée');

    }

    return $this->render('account/form-comment.html.twig', array(
      'form_comment' => $form_comment->createView(),
      'post_id' => $post_id
    ));

}
```

Get Name in the Form Type (for unique id)

```
public function getName() {
    return self::NAME . '_' . uniqid();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response !

Finaly, the problem was not here. I used a specific twig view for my comment form `form-comment.html.twig` (include in the index) but I did not specify a specific route path.

Two responses elements :

**First** : I use `{{ render(url('comment-add')) }}` instead of `render(controller("AppBundle:Default:method")` for include the twig view.

**Second** : I specify a path for action comment post with my route-name (comment-add). `{{ form_start(form_comment, {'attr': {'method' : 'post', 'action' : path('comment-add', {'post_id': post_id, 'groupe_id' : groupe_id})}}) }}`

(I'm sorry because I had not specified that I used a form with include twig view.)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, the problem comes from the `getName()` method with `uniqid()`. 
The name in your controller is not the same as your twig so your form is not valid.

I suppose you want to change the name of the form to have different ids in your view, if that is the case, you can put an id in your form like this:

```
{{ form_start(form_comment, {'attr': {'id' : uniqvalue}}) }}
```

with `uniqvalue` which may be a counter

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely is using `uniqid()` when forming form type name. You see, on first request the comment forms name is for example `form_comment_567c0dff1b74a`, and when user will click submit comment and post data to server, symfony will create form again and bind requests post data to the form, this is how symfony forms work, and in this case, forms name will be different from the name I wrote above. Because of this, `$form_comment->isSubmitted()` will be `false`. Have you simply tried without using `uniqid()`? I am pretty sure that it will work simply naming form type like usually, static name.